# c# form running after close

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have an app with 2 forms. Form1 have the pictureBox and buttons, Form2 has a code that, when i call the form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   new Form2().Show(); 
}
```

it turns is a Zoom Lens, that i can use in Form1 pictureBox.

Problem is, when Form2(lens) is runing and i click ESC to close the form2, it closes but keep increasing consuming memory. Even the errors that form2(lens) has is triggering, like move mouse too far at the border, even after call close to form2.

Here is the code to the Lens form2:

```
PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox(); // Have a picture box
int zoom = 1; // Variable for zoom value
public Form1()
{
    pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // Occupy the full area of the form
    pictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle; // Have a single border of clear representation
    Controls.Add(pictureBox1); // Add the control to the form
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; // Make the form borderless to make it as lens look

    Timer timer = new Timer(); // Have a timer for frequent update
    timer.Interval = 100; // Set the interval for the timer
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick; // Hool the event to perform desire action
    timer.Start(); //Start the timer
    printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height); // Have a bitmap to store the image of the screen         
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image); // Get the image of the captured screen
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size); // Get the copy of screen
    var position = Cursor.Position; // Get the position of cursor
    var lensbmp = new Bitmap(50, 50); // Have a bitmap for lens
    var i = 0; // Variable for row count
    var j = 0; // Variable for column count
    for (int row = position.X - 25; row < position.X + 25; row++) // Indicates row number
    {
        j = 0; // Set column value '0' for new column
        for (int column = position.Y - 25; column < position.Y + 25; column++) // Indicate column number
        {
            lensbmp.SetPixel(i, j, printscreen.GetPixel(row, column)); // Place current region pixel to lens bitmap
            j++; // Increase row count
        }
        i++; // Increase column count
    }
    this.pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(lensbmp, lensbmp.Width * zoom, lensbmp.Height * zoom); // Assign lens bitmap with zoom level to the picture box
    Size = pictureBox1.Image.Size; // Assign optimal value to the form
    Left = position.X + 20; // Place form nearer to cursor X value
    Top = position.Y + 20; // Place form nearer to cursor Y value
    TopMost = true; // Keep the form top level
}

// Override OnKeyDown for zoom in and zoom out actions
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue == 73) // Set "i" as the key for Zoom In.
        zoom++; // Increase zoom by 1 item greater
    else if (e.KeyValue == 79) // Set "o" as the key for Zoom Out
        zoom--; // Decrease zoom by 1 item smaller
    else if (e.KeyValue == 27) // Set "Esc" to close the magnifier
    {
        Close(); // Close the form
        Dispose(); // Dispose the form
    }
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

Is that a way to close this form2 and stop all methods while form1 keep runing? It keep increasing memory consume like 1mb for sec.

Comment: do you open another form from the first form? something like login form that opens the main form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dangerous timer because it isn't declared at the form scope, so it can still keep running.

Declare it at the form level instead:

```
PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
int zoom = 1;
Timer timer = new Timer();

public Form1()
{
    pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // Occupy the full area of the form
    pictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle; // Have a single border of clear representation
    Controls.Add(pictureBox1); // Add the control to the form
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; // Make the form borderless to make it as lens look

    timer.Interval = 100; // Set the interval for the timer
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick; // Hool the event to perform desire action
    timer.Start(); //Start the timer
    printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height); // Have a bitmap to store the image of the screen         
}
```

Also, make sure you dispose of your image and graphic objects, too, when they aren't being used anymore.

Comment: Tnk you my friend. Its exacly that. After that, i just need to call timer.Stop with the close() action. Tnk you.